# VideoView on RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-videoview

I'm developing a social media app which has feed tab based on RecyclerView. On that feed tab I have many types of feedtype like text, photo, photo and text, book, etc... So till now I didn't had any problem about this. On my view holder I've Middle Item Container Panel. I'm putting template which is coming from my feedtypemanager class. So now I need to add videoview for my video feeds. First problem is I'm using rtsp server for streaming. VideoView starting after 15 seconds from seeing that view. Second one is when I scroll down and come up again my VideoView starting from beginnging and I'm waiting 15 seconds again to play that video. So how can I do that view like Instagram fast ? Which protocol I should use and Which VideoPlayer ? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

I've faced the same issues with videoview,

**I would recommend to use [Exomedia](https://github.com/brianwernick/ExoMedia) library and make your life easy with that.**

For smooth video playback use some caching mechanism.
I would recommend [AndroidVideoCache](https://github.com/danikula/AndroidVideoCache) Library.

Use **app:useTextureViewBacking="true"** for smooth animations and transitions of videoview.

Comment: I knew that ExoPlayer but, It doesn't play rtsp protocol. If it would maybe I could get through this but it doesn't :/

Comment: you can use AndroidVideoCache library which can solve your loading problem once its cached.